# Ho to reverse split string into a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use one loop to split or explode a string into an array like

`"Work" // -> var strArray = [k, rk, ork, work]`

I tried `for` loop, but I know this is not an efficient.

```
    for (let index = 0; index < word.length; index++) 
    {
         strArray.push(word[word.length - 1]);
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: so just use substring from the end?

Comment: `word.split("").map((c,i) => word.slice(-1-i))` or `[].map.call(word, (c,i) => word.slice(-1-i))`

Comment: @Thomas i would add a `toLowerCase()` for good measure and create an answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may want to be `slice`ing your string. Here's something that'll do that:

```
function wordSplit(word) {
  let strArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    strArray.push(word.slice(i));
  }
  return strArray;
}
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13kephm9/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string, and iterate the array with Array#map, and generate the string using slice:

```js
var word = 'work';

var result = word.split('').map(function(l, i) {
  return word.slice(-i - 1);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let index = 0; index < word.length; index++) 
    {
         strArray.push(word.slice(index));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

array string elements reversing

```js
function rev(arr){      
    var text = new Array;      
    for(var i= arr.length-1;i>= 0;i--){        
        text.push(arr[i]);   
    }   
    return text.join();         

}  
console.log(rev(["a","b","c"]));
```

```
      `print`
```